# Como poner un fondo en un loader

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

estoy diseñando un loader, la cual es el siguiente:

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 1000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

<div id="loader"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  <h2>Tada!</h2>
  <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
</div>
```

Solo deseo que en mi loader aparezca con un fondo oscuro, por lo cual lo he intentado con este jquery:

```
function setTime() {
     $.blockUI({ message: null }); 
setTimeout(showPage, 1000);
setTimeout($.unblockUI, 1000);
}
```

Pero el fondo oscuro se sobrepone en mi loader,como se ve en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ello pido de su ayuda, no se cual sea el problema y no lo he logrado por resolver, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poner un fondo oscuro debes poner el loader dentro de un div padre que cubra toda la pantalla. El color de div padre (para este ejemplo uso #848484) lo pongo usando la propiedad **background-color**. Cuando uses tus funciones hazla usando el id del div padre y no la del loader.

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 1000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("ParentLoader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.loader-parent{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#848484; /*cambia aqui el color que desea que tenag el fondo*/
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

<div id="ParentLoader" class="loader-parent">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  <h2>Tada!</h2>
  <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: también corregí mi Javascript, vaya no sabia que debía tener un padre, gracias.